# How do I let a user pick where a chart should go using JQPlot?

Tags: jquery, charts, jqplot

I am trying to use JQPlot to do my chart rendering but I am running into an issue. I want the user to be able to select where a chart will be rendered. Say I have 4 quadrants and I want the user to pick top left or top right etc. Is there any way to do this?

From what I've seen JQPlot requires you to specify the div that the plot will go in when you render the plot. Is there any way to pick the div after? Or reassign the div that you originally assign?

Comment: How are you creating these "quadrants"? How is the user going to select one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try tabs like thing to represent the charts, or you can add a html button to show the chart on the desired div. I really don't know your html knowledge. try this also:http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/hiddenPlotsInTabs.html